# HAProxy ALOHA 14-5 exclude specific IP from stats

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to exclude a specific IP(supervision BOT) from HAPROXY ALOHA stats , i dont won't to deny it but to ask HAPROXY not to log the http requests coming from this source and exclude them from the computed stats.
Thanks.

didn't find any solution in the official documentation for that neither in the web